# Is it possible to compare a char to regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if a single character matches a set of possible other characters so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
str.charAt(0) == /[\[\]\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/
```

since it doesn't work is there a right way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `test`

```
/[\[\]\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/.test(str.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use:

```
if(str.charAt(0).match(/[\[\]\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/))
```

`charAt` just returns a one character long string, there is no `char` type in Javascript, so you can use the regular string functions on it to match against a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which is viable as long as you are not using ranges:

```
var chars = "[].,-/#!$%^&*;:{}=-_`~()";

var str = '.abc';
var c = str.charAt(0);

var found = chars.indexOf(c) > 1;
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/esavam

Another option is keeping the characters in an array (for example, using `chars.split('')`), and checking if the character is there:

[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/javascript-array-containsobj)